# Error creating window handle only happens on one machine

Tags: c#, .net

The application is in `c# .net`.

I've tried the application on more than 10 machine, however only one of them gives this error.

Could it be some `.net` problem?

Is there any way I could solve it such as repair/uninstall `.net`?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details on your application and the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only two good reasons for "Error creating window handle".  By far the most common one is that your application is leaking window handles, induced by removing controls from their container with Controls.Clear() or Controls.Remove() and not disposing the control.  That's a permanent leak, Windows pulls the plug after the process has consumed 10,000 window handles.  Diagnose that with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select columns and tick USER Objects.  A steady increase in this value spells trouble.

The second one is much less common, induced by creating a window of a type for which the native DLL that implements the window class is not properly loaded or initialized.  You'd have to use the CreateParams.ClassName property.  The exception is instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

Try [reinstalling your .net framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908077), but I'm not entirely certain this will work, since I'm not sure what the problem is that you're having.

Yeah, I know it applies to 2.0, but it should also work on 3.5. If not, just go to add/remove programs and repair it there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. my fault here. Did not check that the database at the specific machine is different from others :)... thats why it caused that problem.